# Force GNU make to use a specific shell

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to port a project over to a new system, but the makefile has stopped working.  Its important to note that the two computing systems have shared data storage.

In order to juggle the build process, I use several `shell` calls inside the make file.  On the new system, this causes the error

```
make: /usr/bin/sh: Command not found
```

On the new system, the shell executables are located in `/bin/` and on the old system the are located in `/usr/bin`. I haven't explicitly told make to look in `/usr/bin/`, and I dont know how to tell it otherwise.  The only other discussion related to this topic that I could find is about detecting which shell is present, not helping GNU make find the right shell.

[How to detect shell used in GNU make?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40751021/how-to-detect-shell-used-in-gnu-make)

Any ideas about how to solve this problem?

Comment: It's very, very surprising that there's a system out there that doesn't have `/bin/sh` available.  Almost every single shell script ever written includes `#!/bin/sh` and the top and if `/bin/sh` doesn't exist none of them will work.

Comment: the system does have `/bin/sh`, but for some reason `make` is searching for `/usr/bin/sh`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `SHELL` environment variable.  Either set it in the environment (`export SHELL=/bin/sh`) before invoking make, or put `SHELL=/bin/sh` on the make command line.

Likely the problem is actually that you've incorrectly set `SHELL=/usr/bin/sh` in a startup file (.profile or .login or some such) on the new system, which will cause problems for any program that tries to use it, not just make.

Comment: Make never uses the user's setting of `SHELL` (that would be a disaster for portability) so it's not a problem with settings in startup files etc.  Make always uses `/bin/sh` as the setting for `SHELL` by default no matter what the user's `SHELL` variable is set to.  If he is seeing `/usr/bin/sh` then he must have explicitly added `SHELL = /usr/bin/sh` to his makefile.  That's the problem: that line should be removed.

Comment: I don't explicitly set `SHELL=` anywhere in my bashrc or in the makefile, and checking `echo $SHELL` in both systems gives `/bin/bash` as expected.  

Despite this, using `make SHELL=/bin/bash` fixes the issue.    I don't know why make would tend to override the environment variable but this does fix my issue.

Comment: Run this command: `echo 'all:;@echo $(SHELL)' | make -f-`  What does it print out?