# Recursively finding all subdirectories in Make on Windows

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I need to recursively get list of all subdirectories of a given top level directory. On an UNIX system, I can do it like this:

```
SUBDIRS := $(shell find $(TOP_DIR) -type d)
```

However, I need a solution which would be platform independent or at least a solution which works on Windows.

It should be possible to do using recursive wildcards (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483182/recursive-wildcards-in-gnu-make)) but I need to adapt this solution to work for directories instead of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have spaces in your directory names:

```
define dfind
$(foreach d,$1,$(wildcard $d**/) $(call dfind,$(wildcard $d**/)))
endef

SUBDIRS := $(call dfind,$(TOP_DIR)/)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try detect which shell is in use and define variables or functions depending on which. From [How to detect shell used in GNU make?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40751021/how-to-detect-shell-used-in-gnu-make)

```
# detect what shell is used
ifeq ($(findstring cmd.exe,$(SHELL)),cmd.exe)
$(info "shell Windows cmd.exe")
DEVNUL := NUL
WHICH := where
else
$(info "shell Bash")
DEVNUL := /dev/null
WHICH := which
endif
```

Instead (or in addition to) DEVNUL and WHICH you may define FINDDIR. Because of how the arguments work I guess functions is the way to go, see https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Call-Function.html